# Electric field of a circular arc at a point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, integration

Given that the circular arc wire with radius $r$ has a linear charge density $λ$. What is the Electric field at the origin?

[image]

I took a small segment $\mathrm dy$, which is $θ$ above the x-axis with charge $\mathrm dq=λ\,\mathrm dy$. Therefore 
$$d\vec{E}=\frac{kλ\cosθ\,\mathrm dy}{r^2}$$
as all other charges along the y-axis cancel out each other.

Now $\cosθ=x/r$. And $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is the equation of the arc. 
Therefore $\cosθ=\sqrt{r^2−y^2}/r$. And then proceeding to integrate
$$\mathrm d\vec{E}=\frac{kλ\sqrt{r^2−y^2}\,\mathrm dy}{r^3}$$
and arrive at an answer, by integrating in the limits $\pm{r\sin(60^\circ)=\pm{\sqrt{3}r/2}}$.

But my text tackles the question the same way until, at a point it takes $\mathrm dy=r\,\mathrm dθ$ instead of taking it in the form of $\mathrm dy$ and integrating and then substitutes and integrates 
$$\mathrm d\vec{E}=\frac{kλ}{r}\cosθ\,\mathrm dθ$$
and taking the limits as $\theta=\pm{60^\circ}$and arriving at an answer. But my answer differs from the one arrived by my textbook. Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first mistake is that you considered $\mathrm dq=\lambda\,\mathrm dy$. If you look closely, as you go up from the origin to higher $y$, you find that charge density per unit $y$ increases. Take instead $\lambda$ as charge per unit circumference of the wire:
$$\lambda={\mathrm dq \over \mathrm dl} ={\mathrm dq \over r\mathrm d\theta}$$

Now, 
\begin{align}
\mathrm dE&= {k\lambda\,\mathrm dl \over r^2} \cos{\theta} \\
&={k\lambda r\,\mathrm d\theta \over r^2} \cos{\theta}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
E=\int_0^E\mathrm dE&= \int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi /3} {k\lambda  \over r} \cos{\theta} \,\mathrm d\theta \\
&=\frac{k\lambda}{r}\cdot\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{3}-\sin\frac{-\pi}{3}\right) \\
&=\frac{k\lambda}{r}\cdot\sqrt{3}
\end{align}
where $r$ is the radius of the arc.

Comment: Simha - Thanks a lot. I didn't consider that part. I thought that as we limit the segment of a wire into a point it didn't matter how we take it. 

But won't my answer be close to the actual one?

Comment: How much **does** your answer differ from the actual one ? Think about it. Such questions are best answered when done so by yourself.